# Which of these sports requires a definite winner and loser?

Tags: rules, baseball, american-football, basketball

From what I can see, the following sports require that there has to be a winner/loser (draws aren't possible due to some continuation rule that leads to a winning result):

- Basketball
- Baseball
- American Football
- Tennis
- Cricket
- Darts

Can some who's more familiar with any of these sports confirm or correct this impression?

Comment: American football has ties even though you don’t see them often. Also just because there is an overtime or multiple games doesn’t mean their can’t be ties or draws.

Comment: @JoeW Thanks - of all of my list, American Football I was the most doubtful of. When I say 'best of 3' I'm thinking of the likes of tennis whereby it's the first to a certain number of sets which would be played out one a particular night and is considered on stage (like a semi-final of a competition) as opposed to something like a series in in the NBA finals where each would be considered a game in their own right (if that makes sense?) On any given night you were to go to a basketball game for example, there will always be a winner/loser - right?

Comment: There is no difference between a best of 3 in table tennis and basketball. In both cases if the current game won't end because of the score it does not matter how many more games there are in the series.

Comment: I would also point out that the reason you don't see ties in baseball and basketball is that for some reason the American sports fan hates ties.

Comment: @JoeW I get that, but that would mean that each individual game has to have a winner/loser outcome - to put it another way, in a 5-game series that goes down to the last game it'll be because they're both won 2 games each rather then 1 game each and 2 drawn games (or 4 drawn games)

Comment: Well to be fair in most sports where you are talking about a multi game series it is normally during a tournament which generally throws ties out and play until there is a winner

Comment: @JoeW Ok, in the example of basketball, has there ever been a drawn game? is it even possible?

Comment: I've taken out the second half of this question asking for a list of more sports, as I feel the list is just too big: off the top of my head, I can already think of volleyball, table tennis, handball, squash, badminton, ... Answering about the six sports listed in the question seems on-topic though.

Comment: Of course there has been. What you are forgetting is that there are many different rule sets for basketball depending on the competitive level and league.

Comment: Folks: please answer in answers, not in comments. If you have an answer, even a partial one, it's better as an answer rather than in an already overcrowded comment thread.

Answer (score 1):

Barring *force majeure* (police emergencies, building unsafe, etc) of your list:

1. Basketball: always has a result. As many overtime periods as necessary are played, at least under NBA and FIBA rules.
2. Baseball: just about always has a result. As many extra innings as necessary are played - the only exception in MLB is if weather interrupts a game at the end of the season with no playoff implications in which case they may never finish the game.
3. American football: NFL regular season matches have only one 15 minute sort-of sudden death overtime period. NFL playoff matches continue indefinitely.
4. Tennis: always has a result, via a tie-breaker in most tournaments, but three of the four Grand Slams play "2 games clear" in the final set; in the most extreme case, [138 games were played in the final set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isner%E2%80%93Mahut_match_at_the_2010_Wimbledon_Championships).
5. Cricket: Limited overs can result in a tie (or a no result if an insufficient number of overs are bowled); the tie is sometimes broken via a "super over", but not in all cases. Timed matches can result in [either a draw *or* a tie](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17351/what-is-the-concept-of-test-cricket-how-and-when-is-it-decided-that-a-team-has).
6. Darts - I *think* always has a result, but I'm not that au fait with the various competitions.

Comment: WBSC rules allow for a tie when the game is called by the umpire and it is a regulation game (rule 7.01.a). A tied game remains a draw under these circumstances, unless a result is otherwise required for competition purposes.

Comment: MLB Baseball also allows ties for All-Star games, admittedly a special circumstance though.